# assign a new value to multiple column

Tags: r, if-statement

I was trying to assign a new value (recode) multiples column with R using `ifelse`. I was wondering if is possible to select all the columns I want to recode in one step, instead of multiple `ifelse` cycle

```
df <- data.frame(letters[1:10],
                 letters[1:2],
                 rep(c("HemoSeq1", "PLG_FL1"), each=5),
                 rep(0:4, each=2),
                 rep(4:0, each=2),
                 rep(4:0,each=2),
                 rep(0:4,each=2))
names(df) <-c("Sample", "Project", "Bait.Set", "ge1", "ge2", "ge3", "ge4")

df$ge1 <- ifelse(df$ge1 >= 1, 1, 0)
....
df$ge4 <- ifelse(df$ge4 >= 1, 1, 0)
```

or using a for cycle

```
for(i in 4:7) {
    df[i] <- ifelse(df[i] >= 1, 1, 0)
}
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign all columns in one go like this

```
df[4:7] <- df[4:7] >= 1               # Gives you the result as logicals
df[4:7] <- as.integer(df[4:7] >= 1)   # Gives you the result as integers
```

This is a so called "vectorized" operation, not involving explicit loops like `for` or `lapply`. Always strive to use these if you have a lot of data, as they are enormously much faster than non-vectorized solutions.

Answer (score 0):

```
gt1 <- df[,4:7] >= 1
df[,4:7][gt1] <- 1
df[,4:7][!gt1] <- 0
```

you can replace every instance of `4:7` with the relevant integer or character vector of columns